# CPQ How Net Total is Calculated?

Tags: cpq

I have observed one thing When calculating `Net Total`, following things I did

1. For Start Date - **8/1/2020** and End Date **3/15/2024**
   I added segments as follow 
   [image: Product Segments]

Now, when I hit Save for Term of Every year(Span of 12 Months) its showing me `USD 959,354.38`
[image]

This is one part.

Now I went ahead and I changed the segments for Term starting from 3/16/2021 to 3/15/2023 segment like following, earlier therew were Two segments each of 12 Months now its one segment of 24 Months and one Segment of 12 Month for **Same Product**

[image]
When I hit Save it gave me output like following
[image]

So whats happening is for the Term of 12 Months when all segments added are of 12 Months each it is showing the Amount as `USD 959,354.38` but for same product when I added segment for 24 Months what I am expecting it would show me as 
`USD 959,354.38`  * 2 = `19,18,708.76' but the actual value got displayed on Quote Line is`1,918,674.49'

If I take out difference its `19,18,708.76 - 1,918,674.49 = 34.27`  .
I wanted to understand how does CPQ calculates in background , whats the logic behind ? for Same product AMount for 12 Months showing correct but when the segment is of 24 months I am expecting it to be multiplied by 2 but amount is something different.

I know the formula is 
`IF(AND(SBQQ__Renewal__c, !SBQQ__Existing__c, ISBLANK(SBQQ__PriorQuantity__c)), 0, SBQQ__NetPrice__c * SBQQ__EffectiveQuantity__c)`

For more details I have added more details around calculations , check following:
[image]
But I am just trying to understand if logically its correct or not.
If any one could explain me this logic for `Net Total` it will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is setting in CPQ `Unit Price Scale` which tells system how many decimal places system needs to consider when calculating amount.
 [image]

Salesforce I think internally considers decimals up to 30 so I did update the `Unit Price Scale` to 30 and it brought me to more close number. Earlier it was up to 2 decimals that is why there was difference in amount.
[image]